# Error is 'list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple'

Tags: python, list, tuples, slice

I have 2 matrix (`lat` and `lon`) of geograhical data in degrees. I want to convert them to x-y coords for plotting. Error shown is
`list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`. I am new to python and programming. kindly help

```py
ew=lon*(180/np.pi)
ns=lat*(180/np.pi)
ew1=[[0]*3600]*1000
ns1=[[0]*3600]*1000  
for a in range(0,len(ew1)):
   for b in range(0,len(ew1[0])):  
       ew1[a,b]=ew[a,b]-ew[0,0] # ew[0,0]=center lon coord
       ns1[a,b]=ns[a,b]-ns[0,91] ## ns[0,91]=center lat coord
```

The errror message shown at line `ew1[a,b]=ew[a,b]-ew[0,0]`:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: FYI, `ew1=[[0]*3600]*1000` is *extremely* wrong; you just made a `list` that contains 1000 aliases to the *same* 3600 element `list`.

Comment: So ew1and ns1 was not even being defined as  an array. Thanks for pointing out the error. Thanks very much for replying.

Answer (score 0):

To index a 2d list you use `ew1[a][b]` instead of `ew1[a,b]`:

```
ew1[a][b] = ew[a][b] - ew[0,0]
ns1[a][b] = ns[a][b] - ns[0,91]
```

Although there's also [common 2d list issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly).

But as you are using numpy you can (and should) do:

```
ew = lon * (180 / np.pi)
ns = lat * (180 / np.pi)
ew1 = ew - ew[0,0]
ns1 = ns - ns[0,91]
```